# Camera Linecast Bumper Stuttery

Tags: unity, c#, camera, scripting

I copied a script off the internet and changed it a bit:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (target)
    {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        RaycastHit hit;
        //Over here is probably where the problem occurs
        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
        {
            if (!hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                distance = hit.distance;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            distance = 10f;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

I made it so that if the `RaycastHit`'s `collider` is `null`, that the distance would be reset at 10. Whenever the `RaycastHit` is hit, it will move the camera distance closer to the player as to get in front of the object blocking the view. All nice and dandy, but when I run the game, when I get in front of and object, it works as planned but it is very stuttery, I have a hunch it has something to do with the if statement for the linecast but I have no idea how to fix it, I tried changing `LateUpdate` to `FixedUpdate` and to `Update` but it still occurs. I'm still new to unity and c# so forgive me if this was a simple mistake.

Here is a video showing it happening: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6ffVmq1UWs

Comment: The Update mode does not influence the result: -Update: update the game logic every frame: -FixedUpdate: used as Update but is better with physics - LateUpdate: runs before the Update method

Comment: In order to optimize your script a little bit: Remove the condition `if( !PhysicsLinecast ....` and keep only the `else`. Otherwise, you cast **two** rays instead of one. The 2nd one is useless. And I think `if (hit.collider != null)` should be removed. The collider will never be null. Otherwise, the `Linecast` would have not detected it.

Comment: @Hellium Oh I see, thanks for telling me. Since it is like that, is there any other way to detect if there is nothing behind the camera so it can be set back to the default distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure at all about the following.

Instead of Linecasting between the **current** position of the camera and the target, I would linecast between the **desired** position and the target.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (target)
    {
        // Reset to the desired distance
        distance = 10 ;
        // OR the following line if you want smoother reset
        // distance = Mathf.Lerp(distance, 10, Time.deltaTime * 5);

        // Rotate according to mouse position
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

        // Compute the desired position
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

        RaycastHit hit;

        // Check if there is an obstacle between the desired position
        // and the target
        if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, position, out hit) && !hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            // Obstacle detected !
            // Computing the new position so that
            // the object is on the other side of the obstacle
            distance = hit.distance;
            negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -hit.distance);
            position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;
        }

        // Placing the object
        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, still stuttery, im starting to think using a linecast was a bad idea, should i use a collider instead?

Comment: It seems to work fine here. I've just forgotten to reset `distance` to `10` before assigning the other values (answer updated)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much. Please do explain to me what you did and why.

Comment: Glad it worked.
As I indicated, I compute the desired position first. I call `Linecast` to check if I can place the camera at the desired location. If not, I place the camera at the collision point, like you did in your original script.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Comments added to my answer ;)